# Promise always returns the initial value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

having a bit of a problem with promises in angularjs.
My promises 'get cached', meaning they always return the initial value they got called with. I'm pretty familiar with promises from other places, but new to angularJS, so please help me shed a light on my problem, I'm probably not understanding something very basic here

I am using a factory:

```
.factory('Traffic', function ($http) {
    var trafficUrl = 'some url';
    var httpPromise = $http.get(trafficUrl, {cache: false} );
    var invalidateCache = function() {
        return $http.get(trafficUrl, {cache: false} );
    }

    return {
        all: function () {
          httpPromise = invalidateCache();
            return httpPromise
              .then(function (response) {
                //parsing the response and returning stuff (not promise)
        }

    }
})
```

which is sending a request, and parsing it for the first time.
now `invalidateCache` was suggested by someone to avoid exactly my problem (assign a new `$http.get` each time to avoid it referring to the same, initial promise).

now my controller:
.controller('TrafficCtrl', function ($interval, $ionicLoading, $scope, Traffic) {

```
var getJams = function () {
      var traffic = Traffic.all();
      traffic.then(function (response) {
            //doing stuff with the response
        })
    };

    $scope.refresh = function () {
      getJams();
    }
})
```

now, each time I invoke `$scope.refresh` method, I see the items getting 'refreshed' (console.log gets called inside `getJams`) but the values stay as the first called `getJams()`.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you turn on your network traffic and see what it is capturing? I wonder if the $http response is being cached even though you are telling angular not to. Is it making subsequent network requests? Is browser saying response was cached when it returns?

Comment: just to clarify - is the ajax call executing and reaching to the server? are you sure about it ? please check that and inform us.

Comment: @Patrick seems like you were right, the response is `from cache`, so the problem is not here. so my new question is, how do I disable this cache ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, it sounds like the browser is caching your response, so you will want to update the server logic to set Cache specific headers.

You will probably want to add the following Cache-Control header to your response:

Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache

A little more info about the cache headers [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en).

Should be able to find plenty of examples to set this in your server side language of choice.

Also, you can clean up the code much more:

```
.factory('Traffic', function ($http) {
    var trafficUrl = 'some url';

    return {
        all: function () {
          // don't need the invalidate call anymore
          return $http.get(trafficUrl).then(function (response) {
                //parsing the response and returning stuff (not promise)
        }

    }
})
```

And your controller:

```
var getJams = function () {
      // No need to store the initial promise call, just chain them.
      Traffic.all().then(function (response) {
            //doing stuff with the response
        })
    };
```